# How to scrape all product relevant images from product detail page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Good morning
Thank you for your help

Here is my new code. I don't know if I incorporated the code you suggest correctly.

Here is my code:

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
  
page = requests.get("https://www.boulanger.com/ref/1176193")

if page.status_code == 200:
    parsedPage = bs(page.content, 'lxml')
    div_product = parsedPage.find('article',{'class':'container-xl'})
    title = div_product.find('h1',{'class':'product-title__main'}).get_text()
    title = '\n'.join([ligne.strip() for ligne in title.split('\n') if ligne.strip() != '']).replace('\n', ' ')
    ref = div_product.find('div',{'class':'product-title__ref'}).get_text()
    data = json.loads(
            bs(
                requests.get(page).content
            ).select_one('script:has(+header)').text
        )
    media_data = json.loads(requests.get(f'https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/Boulanger/{data.get("gtin13")}_mixed?req=set,json,UTF-8').text.split('(')[1][:-5])
    
    short_desc = div_product.find('section',{'class':'keypoints'})
    long_desc = div_product.find('div',{'class':'product-features__content'})
    #data = {
     #   'titre': title,
     #   'ref': ref,
     #   'foto': img_link
      #  }
    print(long_desc)
```

Comment: A nice puzzle for your first post - For future ones the information could be improved a bit, so feel free to take a few minutes for the [tour] and the points [ask] and How to create [mcve] - Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 0):

A python newbie too. :)

This web page may use asynchronous loading methods such as ajax, and using python's requests library directly can only get the static source code of the web page. In this static source code(you can use ctrl+U to have a look), you can't find the class element ('div',{'class':'thumb'}). That's why your python interpreter shows the error message.

Maybe You can use f12 to access your browser console to grab the network traffic and find the real link to the images of this item and analyse the url's rules to crawl all of them down.

Here are links of the first three images: [img1](https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/Boulanger/8806092967915_h_f_l_0), [img2](https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/Boulanger/8806092967915_h_f_l_1), [img3](https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/Boulanger/8806092967915_h_f_l_2)......

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

*Always and first of all, take a look at your `soup` or use `ctrl+U` for static source to see if all the expected ingredients are in place.*

---

The main point is that the content of the page is compiled and rendered dynamically, which is not supported by `requests` per se. Only a small amount of information is available when the page is initially called up, but we can use this, without out invoke alternatives like `selenium` that mimics browser behavior.

**Step#1:** Use `BeautifulSoup` to find the `<script>` with the product information.

```
data = json.loads(
        BeautifulSoup(
            requests.get(url).content
        ).select_one('script:has(+header)').text
    )
```

**Step#2:** Extract the value of the identifier `gtin13`.

```
data.get("gtin13")
```

**Step#3:** Use the extracted value to call the scene7 api and extract the JSON structur

```
media_data = json.loads(requests.get(f'https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/Boulanger/{data.get("gtin13")}_mixed?req=set,json,UTF-8').text.split('(')[1][:-5])
```

**Step#4:** iterate over the items and extract the paths

```
[f'https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/{e["i"]["n"]}' for e in media_data['set']['item']]
```

*Last but not least, you can also add the list to `data` and you will probably have all the relevant information in a structured dictionary.*

```
data['media_list'] = [f'https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/{e["i"]["n"]}' for e in media_data['set']['item']]
```

---

###### Example

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.boulanger.com/ref/1176193'
data = json.loads(
            BeautifulSoup(
                requests.get(url).content
            ).select_one('script:has(+header)').text
        )
media_data = json.loads(requests.get(f'https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/Boulanger/{data.get("gtin13")}_mixed?req=set,json,UTF-8').text.split('(')[1][:-5])

[f'https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/{e["i"]["n"]}' for e in media_data['set']['item']]
```

###### Output

```
['https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/Boulanger/8806092967915_h_f_l_0',
 'https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/Boulanger/8806092967915_h_f_l_1',
 'https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/Boulanger/8806092967915_h_f_l_2',
 'https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/Boulanger/8806092967915_h_f_l_3',
 'https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/Boulanger/8806092967915_h_f_l_4',
 'https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/Boulanger/8806092967915_h_f_l_5',
 'https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/Boulanger/8806092967915_h_f_l_6',
 'https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/Boulanger/8806092967915_h_f_l_7',
 'https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/Boulanger/8806092967915_h_f_l_8',
 'https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/Boulanger/8806092967915_h_e_l_0',
 'https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/Boulanger/8806092967915_h_b_l_0',
 'https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/Boulanger/8806092967915_h_b_l_1',
 'https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/Boulanger/8806092967915_h_b_l_2',
 'https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/Boulanger/8806092967915_h_b_l_3',
 'https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/Boulanger/8806092967915_h_b_l_4',
 'https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/Boulanger/8806092967915_h_b_l_5',
 'https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/Boulanger/8806092967915_h_b_l_6',
 'https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/Boulanger/8806092967915_v_0']
```